# Two primitive roots add to a third

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

Primitive roots are useful in analyzing the multiplicative structure of the numbers mod $p$, for $p$ a prime. I wondered if there was anything that could link the multiplicative and additive structure together. I thus came up with the following conjecture:

> For all sufficiently large primes $p$, there are two different primitive roots mod $p$ adding to a third.

Given the large proportion of primitive roots a number usually has, this seems quite plausible. A preliminary computer search shows that the conjecture holds for $p = 11$ and $17 \le p \le 1{,}000$. The primes $p \in \{2, 3, 5, 7, 13\}$ are counterexamples.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I've reworded the conjecture slightly.

Comment: I might change "arbitrarily large" in the statement to "sufficiently large".  "A preliminary computer search ..." of what?  Did you show that for $p < 17$ the conjecture fails?  Did you show that there are no counterexamples for $17 \leq p \leq {}$ some unstated stopping point for the search?

Comment: Yeah, I tested the first thousand primes before finding a quite complicated proof. A friend then found a much more succinct argument.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, your second hypothetical interpretation would be formulated thus: "there exist arbitrarily large primes $p$ such that, there exist 2 different primitive roots mod $p$ whose sum is a primitive root mod $p$". The answer would be easily yes: for all $M$ we can take an arbitrarily large prime $q>M$, then take a prime $p>q+3>M$ such that $3$, $q$, and $q+3$ are coprime to $p-1$ then we are done, mod $p$.

Comment: Have a vague memory that the number of primitive roots for prime $p$ is $\phi(p-1)$ where $phi$ is Euler's Totient function. I don't know where to go from there, thought it might help.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is due to a colleague, which is why I'm marking it as a community wiki. Surprisingly, we're able to prove the bound $p \ge 17$ directly.

We first prove that mod $p \ge 17$, there's a sixth power $a$ and a square $b$, neither in $\{0, 1\}$, with difference $1$. Let $g$ be a primitive root mod $p$ such that $g^{12} \ne 2$, which exists as either a primitive root or its reciprocal satisfies this. Note also that $g^6 \ne \pm 1$. If either of $g^6 \pm 1$ is a quadratic residue, we're done. Otherwise, $g^{12}$ and $(g^6 - 1)(g^6 + 1) = g^{12} - 1$ satisfy the desired property.

Now, for $g$ a primitive root mod $p$, write $a = g^{6m}$, $b = g^{2n}$. Note that among the numbers $\{6m, 2n, 0\}$, only one congruence mod $2$ and at most two congruences mod $3$ are represented. By the Chinese residue theorem, we can find some $k \ne 0$ such that for any prime $q$ coprime with $p - 1$,
$$k \not\equiv -6m,\,-2n,\,0 \pmod q.$$
Then the numbers $g^{6m+k}$, $g^{2n+k}$, $g^k$ are distinct primitive roots, and two of them add to the third.

Comment: Thank you. Just to be sure: you asked the question for the record - you had the answer prior to asking ? How long did it take your colleague to get the answer ?

Comment: @plm Yes, I wanted to record this question online as I found the solution really elegant. It took him about 4 hours.